# Postman: Connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5005

Tags: node.js, rest, postman

I have developed an API endpoint. It was working fine before. Unfortunately the project folder got corrupted (I recreated the files db.js and server.js). But now when I try to fetch data from API, I'm getting:

```
"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5005"
```

[image]

The URL I'm using is localhost:

[image]

And my server is running on the same port i.e. 5005:
[image]

Can someone please elaborate what can be the problem? My hunch is that when I recreated the files I may have missed something:

db.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userName = "myUsername"
const password = "myPassword"
const dbName = "comfyRooms"

const dbURL = `mongodb+srv://${userName}:${password}@mongo-cluster.damzf.mongodb.net/${dbName}?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-s7z01e-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true`

mongoose.connect(dbURL, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
let connection = mongoose.connection

connection.on('error', () => {
    console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB')
})

connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB connection established :)")
})

module.exports = mongoose
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const dbConfig = require('./db')
const roomsRoute = require('./routes/roomsRoute')

app.use('/api/rooms', roomsRoute)

const port = process.env.PORT || 5005

app.listen(() => {
    console.log("Node JS server listening on port " + port)
})
```

roomsRoute.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Room = require('../models/rooms');

router.get('/getallrooms', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const rooms = await Room.find({});
        return res.send(rooms);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: error});
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have attached the important files. Please let me know if any other information is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the port variable to the listen function, you are just logging it

```
app.listen(() => {
console.log("Node JS server listening on port " + port)
})
```

This should work

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Node JS server listening on port " + port)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe I overlooked this. Really hope there should be some error mechanism in place that points such errors. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Ashar Yeah, that would be nice. No problem!